# Btrfs Send Snapshots Out of Order? (asynchronous replication)

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, snapshot

I found this webpage on the internet discussing sending Btrfs incremental snapshots out of order.

https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1226135

From there, I've searched all over the internet and haven't found anything else about this (asynchronous replication?).

For example I have the snapshots:

```
$ btrfs sub snapshot dir snaps/1
$ btrfs sub snapshot dir snaps/2
$ btrfs sub snapshot dir snaps/3
```

How would I efficiently `btrfs send` 1 then 3 then 2?

Also, later in the webpage it says "can go backwards if you need to". Is it possible I could `btrfs send` 3 then 2 then 1? How?

Also, would sending out of order take up more space on the receiving side than sending in order?

Here is the closest thing I could find as a clue, but the examples it uses are difficult for me to understand: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_-c_and_-p_in_send.3F

Answer (score 0):

```
# Send 3 then 1 then 2
btrfs send 3
btrfs send -c 3 1      # Send 1 and Subtract data matching 3
btrfs send -c 3 -p 1 2 # Send 2 with Parent of 1, and Subtract data matching 3

# Send 3 then 2 then 1
btrfs send 3
btrfs send -c 3 2      # Send 2 and Subtract data matching 3
btrfs send -c 3 -c 2 1 # Send 1 and Subtract data matching 2 and 3
```